# Shift+Option+Arrow (left/right) to select one word not working in VSCode and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently switched from one Macbook Pro to another (recently updated to Big Sur, but I don't know if the shortcut worked beforehand because I upgraded it right away) and shift+option+left/shift+option+right no longer works as a shortcut in VSCode or Chrome to jump the text selection to the beginning/end of a word. Cmd+shift+arrow works fine to get me to the end of a sentence though.

Interestingly enough, it works in safari, notes, microsoft word, etc. The only programs (and the most important ones) where it is not working are VSCode and Chrome.

I've tried reconfiguring my VSCode key bindings, but that hasn't worked. I tried looking up how to reconfigure for chrome and didn't find much.

I imagine there's some program on my laptop that is preventing this shortcut from working, but how do I find it?

Edit: I'm also on the latest version of VSCode, 1.43.2